# Bash script with multiple string arguments

Tags: java, string, bash

I'm having problem separating two string variables as arguments for a bash script. My bash script takes two arguments like so:

```
#!/bin/bash


DATA1=$1
DATA2=$2
```

However, DATA1 and DATA2 are not what I intended, because bash is reading my strings wrongly. DATA2 is only the first part of the argument I wanted to put in, because I'm having trouble making a complicated(relatively) string into a single arguemnt.

I call this script from a Java app with variables like this:

```
String m1 = "some data";
String m2 = "some more"+mystring+"even more data"+anotherstring;


myscript.sh  m1 m2
```

Only the first part of m2 is passed to DATA1 in  the bash script. I've tried wrapping the whole thing in single quotes and double quotes I can't get it to accept the whole of m2 as the second argument.

Any help in creating two string arguments is appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is more likely to be on the Java end than on the Bash end. How are you launching the script?

Comment: You are going to have to show the EXACT code you use to invoke the script from Java (`Runtime.exec()`?, `ProcessBuilder`?), including the code that sets up the arguments.  Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: first part of m2 is passed to DATA1? do you mean first part of m2 is passed to DATA2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me, see:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "/tmp/myscript.sh", m1,m2});
```

---

Your code calls:`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String)`

It calls method `exec(command,null,null)` (see source code in src.zip) [exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29) .

Method exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir) parse command by StringTokenizer. So text `"some data"` or `"\"some data\""` is split to `some` `data` (or `"some` `data "`)